# Raspberry pi 4 - with custom GUI interface and fast boot speed

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

I'm trying to achieve this on a Raspberry Pi 4:

- Less then 10 seconds boot time
- Custom UI ( build with python/Gtk for example )

I already tried editing the /boot/config.txt with

```
# Disable the rainbow splash screen
disable_splash=1
# Disable bluetooth
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
#Disable Wifi
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-wifi
dtoverlay=sdtweak,overclock_50=100
# Set the bootloader delay to 0 seconds. The default is 1s if not specified.
boot_delay=0
# Overclock the raspberry pi. This voids its warranty. Make sure you have a good power supply.
force_turbo=1
```

Also I have an A2 class 10 SdCard and I have disabled almost every service that I don't need.

My best results are 14 seconds boot time until my app started, but I need to make it faster....

I would like to achieve something like this in terms of speed, but using GTK, not QT:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTcP3xeLrEY

Comment: Please provide some [MRE] in your question. Consider perhaps using directly [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) at a very low level (so code  your stuff in C, not in Python). Can you afford spending months of your time for a 30% speedup?

Comment: Have you measured what's taking the time? Maybe make a beep before you start your app for timing it? Are you using a lightweight window manager? Do you need a window manager, maybe you can use the framebuffer?

Comment: My first problem is how to make Raspberry boot faster. How can I do that ?

Comment: Please define what do you mean by "Raspberry boot". I am sure your `/sbin/init` process starts in less than a second

Comment: How many years of work can you budget to achieve your goals? Without a lot more details, your question is unclear.

Comment: The best would be to find an already made image for my pi that starts in seconds. I don't have a budget and a time for this.

Answer (score 3):

I am also currently trying to reach fast boot time with my Raspberry Pi 4, but I cannot breach the wall of 10s without radical solutions such as buildroot or unikernel.

What do you need on your system ? On Raspbian you can use those two commands to verify what is slowing down the boot process :

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

and

```
 systemd-analyze blame
```

Critical chain will show in red the services blocking the boot.
On my setup I could desactivate all those services :

```
 hciuart #GPIOs
 nmbd    
 smbd
 wpa_supplicant
 systemd-timesyncd
 rpi-eeprom-update.service
 raspi-config.service
 networking
```

Just use `sudo systemctl disable SERVICE` , I guess there are others that are not critical for your application.
Also, in the cmdline.txt file in /boot you can add `quiet fastboot` , it will decrease boot time further

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know about the critical-chain and blame commands, and I already disable them. I'm also stuck on 10s boot time until it starts and if i add a window manager ( openbox for example ) it's going into 14s.
I also tried with buildroot but it seems difficult to use if i don't know what to select there.

Comment: There is this guide which is quite good but it's not going too much into details : https://himeshp.blogspot.com/2018/08/fast-boot-with-raspberry-pi.html  , also this one : https://www.furkantokac.com/rpi3-fast-boot-less-than-2-seconds/ , it is not for Pi4 but still mostly valid. Have you checked that ?

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do this @Varech, with Pyhton and pyGame: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjjET56Ct3w

Comment: Awesome ! Did you have to custom (remove stuff) a lot to reach such a result ?

Comment: Yes, your link ( furkantokac.com ) helped me a lot. All I added ( after 10000 failed tests with X11 server ) was python and pyGame module. It seems that pyGame is using direct OpenGL access and it's working without the XORG server.

Answer (score 2):

#### [GTK](https://gtk.org/) is a toolkit coded in C and callable from C code.

#### In practice, Python can be 10x slower than equivalent C code.

Did you consider starting [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) with a minimal window manager and a single client coded in C? Without a single line of Python? Of course, read more about [X windows systems protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture) and architecture then about [EWMH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints).

So, **remove the Python interpreter** on your RaspBerryPi (probably `/usr/bin/python`) and **replace every old Python script by an equivalent [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable coded in C** or in C++ and compiled with optimizations (so `gcc -O3` with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)). See also [linuxfromscratch.org](http://linuxfromscratch.org/) for inspiration and guidance.

> I would like to achieve something like this in terms of speed, but using GTK

Of course, you want to use a GCC [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).

If that still does not work (after weeks of effort), replace your hardware by something more powerful.

It would be easier for you to install a Linux distribution such as [Debian](https://debian.org/) on your development laptop or desktop. Because most of what you would learn on your development computer (e.g. [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)) can be applied to the RaspBerrry Pi. And cross-building on a Debian laptop for a [Raspbian](https://www.raspbian.org/) RaspBerryPi is *really* easy. Focus on learning low-level things starting from their C code. E.g. code your GUI directly with [Xlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib) (no GTK, no Qt) in C. The same C code is very likely to be easily [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) -if you write it carefully- from x86/Debian to your Raspberry Pi.

You could read the [*From powerup to to bash prompt howto*](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/From-PowerUp-To-Bash-Prompt-HOWTO.html); most of that document is relevant for a RaspBerryPi running RaspBian.

You could even avoid starting any Xorg or other [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) (e.g. [WayLand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol))) on your RaspBerryPi. That certainly would make it boot faster.

You could replace your `/sbin/init`  [program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) by your own one coded in C entirely. That process starts within less than a second, and forks all other processes. Your custom GUI could be just `Xorg` with your single X11 client coded in C.

Observe that you  could have the source code (millions of source lines) of all the code running on RaspBian. Then download it, study it, and optimize it. Of course this could take decades.

Comment: Okay, let’s say I will make it in simple C. But how do I make the Raspberry boot faster ?

Comment: Define what is your boot process. Read relevant documentation. On PC, the boot itself (loading of kernel and of initrd) happens in centisecond. The *startup* is longer (starting all processes, including daemons and servers)

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a poorly formed question. You've provided no details on what your boot process is or what OS/configuration you're running with for people to help.

Regardless, you appear primarily focused on a short boot time. So since your question is generic... here is a generic answer: there is nothing magical about the boot process. There is no config file with a fast_boot=1 option that gets you up in 0 seconds instead of 15. You want to boot faster? Do less.

1. Throw out slow crap like Python
2. Remove unnecessary application loading from your init system (sysvinit/systemd/whatever)
3. Remove unnecessary driver loading from the kernel startup. Start by trimming down your device tree to only the hardware you really need to initialize.
4. Optimize your bootloader (u-boot?) to only initialize the hardware you really need (obviously turn off any prompt and timer it may implement)

That's how you boot faster.

Comment: I didn't mention any OS name because I'm willing to change it. My tests are made with Raspbian Lite. configuration is the standard one for Raspberry Pi 4.
1. ok, i get the python stuff. But until i throw it away, I have to boot in console faster, right?
2. I already disabled almost all services from systemd
3. I don't know how to do this. I have to recompile the kernel? Is there a tutorial for this?
4. I don't know how to do this also.